# angular-ui select2 can not have multiple input with select2Options in same controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-select2

I am using select2 from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

```
// I have two input select2 box inside one controller
<form ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input
type="text"
ui-select2="select2Options"
ng-model="bookmarks"
>
<input
type="text"
ui-select2="select2Options"
ng-model="products"
>
</form>
//In controller I have list of bookmarks and products I am trying something like below but     it is not working and both the input box ended up with same data i.e. products.
function MyCtrl($scope){
var bookmarks=[
    {id:0,text:"enhancement"},
    {id:1,text:"bug"},
    {id:2,text:"duplicate"},
    {id:3,text:"invalid"},
    {id:4,text:"wontfix"}
    ];
$scope.select2Options = {
    multiple: true,
    width: "300px",
    data:bookmarks
};
var products=[
    {id:0,text:"Product1"},
    {id:1,text:"Product2"},
    {id:2,text:"Product3"},
    {id:3,text:"Product4"},
    {id:4,text:"Product5"}
    ];

$scope.select2Options = {
    multiple: true,
    width: "300px",
    data:products
};

 }
```

As you see above code will convert two input box in to select2 input boxes but both box will have products data. I want bookmark input box filled with bookmarks and product input box with products.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 2 separate scope property to store the options for bookmarks and products. In your case the product options is overriding bookmarks options also since the same property is used for both.

Try

```
<form ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ui-select2="bookmarksSelect2Options" ng-model="bookmarks">
    <input type="text" ui-select2="productsSelect2Options" ng-model="products">
</form>
```

and

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var bookmarks = [{
        id: 0,
        text: "enhancement"
    }, {
        id: 1,
        text: "bug"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        text: "duplicate"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        text: "invalid"
    }, {
        id: 4,
        text: "wontfix"
    }];
    $scope.bookmarksSelect2Options = {
        multiple: true,
        width: "300px",
        data: bookmarks
    };
    var products = [{
        id: 0,
        text: "Product1"
    }, {
        id: 1,
        text: "Product2"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        text: "Product3"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        text: "Product4"
    }, {
        id: 4,
        text: "Product5"
    }];

    $scope.productsSelect2Options = {
        multiple: true,
        width: "300px",
        data: products
    };

}
```